# Inequality involving the k:th root of real sequences $a_k$ and $b_k$ for k large

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $a_k \geq 0$ and  $b_k \geq 0$ be real sequences and suppose that $\limsup\limits_{k \rightarrow \infty} \ \sqrt[k]{a_k} \leq 1$ and $\limsup\limits_{k \rightarrow \infty} \ \sqrt[k]{b_k} \leq 1$. Is it true in general that $\limsup\limits_{k \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[k]{a_k+b_k} \leq 1$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the assumptions,
$a_k<(1+c)^k$
and
$b_k<(1+c)^k$
for any $c > 0$
for large enough $k$.

Therefore
$a_k+b_k<2(1+c)^k$
so

$\begin{array}\\
\sqrt[k]{a_k+b_k}
&\le 2^{1/k}(1+c)\\
&< (1+c)^2
\qquad\text{for }2^{1/k} < 1+c\\
&< 1+3c
\qquad\text{for small enough }c\\
\end{array}
$

This does what you want.

Note that this works for
any finite number of summands.
What you want,
for $m$ summands
($m=2$ here),
 is
$m^{1/k} < 1+c$
or
$k > \dfrac{\ln m}{\ln(1+c)}
$.

Comment: Great Marty - thanks!